# Freenas 9.2 and btsync

Tags: freenas

I just got btsync setup on my freenas box. I also installed it onmy computer at work. I want to sync the files between work andmy freenas box.

I got it connected and the sync works but nothing is transferring from my work machine to the freenas box.

I have 2 questions,
the first is will all of my files from the folder that im syincing on my work machine transfer over to my freenas machine?

and i noticed that the limits for upload and download are set to 0 kb/s. should i change that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all the files should sync (just like Dropbox if you use that).

I'm not sure where you're seeing the limits for uploading and downloading but usually in those cases 0 means 'no limit'.